# Slider UI for when HTML5 input type range not supported?

Tags: slider

I need something like the HTML range input for a site im working on but I need it to work with older versions of Android that dont suppor this feature.

```
<input type="range" value="10" min="0" max="100" />
```

Which when supported looks a bit like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Im making a demo only so all I need is the UI, so just a point you can drag along a slider. The site is mobile optimised so needs a touch screen interface, which is why I cant use jQuery UI. Is there a way of doing this without using the jQuery Mobile framework? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive done it with jQuery UI and this hack to get it working with touchscreens: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slider mostly written from scratch. That is, without using any UI libraries. I use jQuery, _ and backbone, but if you don't care about them, they can be replaced with the more primitive versions of browser APIs that do the same. Full sample at http://jsfiddle.net/shyamh/gBNAg/ Touch event support has not been added, but that should not be too hard to wire up.

```
function slider(id, width) {

        var _i = this,

            // todo - can we refactor to get _thumbWidth from element styles?
            _thumbWidth = 24,

            _slideRange = width, 

            // View template for control. Typically this would be outside the class, 
            // so it's reused between multiple instance of this control.
            // The id is bound as a paremeter in the template. There may be other parameters.
            //
            _t = '<div id="<%=id%>" class="slider" style="width:<%=width%>px;">' +
                 '  <div id="<%=id%>_track" class="sliderTrack"></div>' +
                 '  <div id="<%=id%>_thumbcontainer" class="sliderThumbContainer" style="width:' + _thumbWidth + 'px">' +
                 '    <div id="<%=id%>_thumb" class="sliderThumb"></div>' +
                 '  </div>' +
                 '</div>',

            _currentValue = 0,

            _$el = $(_.template(_t, { id: id, width: (width || 100) })),

            _el = _$el[0],

            _elTrack = $('#' + id + '_track:first', _el)[0],
            _elThumbContainer = $('#' + id + '_thumbcontainer:first', _el)[0];

        _.extend(_i, Backbone.Events);

        function x2Percent(x) {
            if (x < 0) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                var p = x / _slideRange * 100;
                if (p > 100) { p = 100; }
                return p;
            }
        }

        function moveThumbToX(x) {
            var offsetLeft = _$el.offset().left,
                p = x2Percent(x - offsetLeft),
                newX = (Math.round(p / 100 * _slideRange) - _thumbWidth / 2);

            newX = (newX < 0) ? 0 : ((newX > (width - _thumbWidth)) ? (width - _thumbWidth) : newX) ;

            _elThumbContainer.style.left = newX + "px";

            _currentValue = p;
        }

        function _elClick(e) {
            moveThumbToX(e.x);
            // todo - fire backbone event for slider changed event
        }

        function _elThumbContainerMouseDown(e) {
            document.addEventListener("mousemove", _mouseMove);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", _mouseUp);
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            // todo - fire backbone event for slider drag-started event
        }

        function _mouseMove(e) {
            var x = e.x;
            e.preventDefault();
            requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                moveThumbToX(e.x);
                // todo - fire backbone event for slider dragging event
            });        
        }

        function _mouseUp(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", _mouseMove);
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", _mouseUp);
            // todo - fire backbone event for slider drag-ended event
        }

        // set the value to p, where p is between 0..100
        _i.setValue = function(p) {
            moveThumbToX(Math.round(p / 100 * _slideRange));    
        }

        _i.getElement = function () {
            return _el;
        }

        var _ctor = function () {
            _el.addEventListener("click", _elClick);
            _elThumbContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", _elThumbContainerMouseDown);
        }();
    }
```